# Spring Jpa - play with multiple findby method in code

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring boot base API on the top of my rdbms system, I do all operations but when it is about selecting the data from the system, my GET mapping endpoint has many checks which decide which findbyAttributes method should I call.

I have created multiple repository methods like findbyId, findbyIdAndName findbyIdAndNameAndAge.

But consider my scenario where I have around 30 columns in the table which the end-user may want to query at some point of time using my GET endpoint, which I have achieved but due to increasing number of request coming for each column/attributes of my entity, my code cognitive complexity increased a lot.

I know there has to be some different way than calling each findby method behind multiple if-else loops which is too bad I guess.

My code looks like this currently -

```
public Page<myEntity> getDataFromDatabase(
      @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String id,
      @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String name,
      @RequestParam(value = "age", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String age,
      @RequestParam(value = "address", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String address,
      Pageable pageable) {

    Page<myEntity> finalData = null;

    if (!id.equals("NA")
        && name.equals("NA")
        && age.equals("NA")
        && address.equals("NA")) {
      finalData = service.findById(id, pageable);

    } else if (id.equals("NA")
        && !name.equals("NA")
        && age.equals("NA")
        && address.equals("NA")) {
      finalData = service.findByName(name, pageable);
    } else if (id.equals("NA")
        && name.equals("NA")
        && !age.equals("NA")
        && address.equals("NA")) {
      finalData = service.findByAge(age, pageable);
    } else if (id.equals("NA")
        && name.equals("NA")
        && age.equals("NA")
        && !address.equals("NA")) {
      finalData = service.findByAddress(address, pageable);
    }else if (!id.equals("NA")
        && !name.equals("NA")
        && !age.equals("NA")
        && !address.equals("NA")) {
      finalData = service.findByIdAndNameAndAgeAndAddress(id,name,age,address, pageable);
    }else if (!id.equals("NA")
        && !name.equals("NA")
        && age.equals("NA")
        && address.equals("NA")) {
      finalData = service.findByIdAndName(id,name, pageable);
    }
    // few more else if as new column is being added
    // I think I did it but this will not last for long 

}
```

Understand if I wanted to add all the findBy attributes based on mentioned conditional logic.

If someone can help on this what would make my day shine.

Note - I read about [Jpa Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) where they map like findAll method logic with multiple specifications which moreover feels like the same as each time I need to create certain condition base calling each get method.

Also, please let me know if it the right approach to go with, my idea is to write less code with best practises, so from GET endpoint all the JpaRepository findby method can be called via framework only I should not have to write multiple if-else.

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider Jpa Specification, this is probably the best solution.
It will be easy to build your specifications with this method, even for 30 attributes.

You can check [Hibernate Query too](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries)

First create a method like this

```
 public Specification<MyEntity>  myEntitySpecification(String id, String name) {
         return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            List<Predicate> predicateList  = new ArrayList<>();
            if (!id.equals("NA")){
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
            }
            if (!name.equals("NA")){
                predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
            }

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]));
        };
    }
```

Then call it

```
    public Page<MyEntity> getDataFromDatabase(
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String id,
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String name,
            @RequestParam(value = "age", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String age,
            @RequestParam(value = "address", required = false, defaultValue = "NA") String address,
            Pageable pageable) {



        Page<MyEntity> finalData = testRepository.findAll(myEntitySpecification(id, name), pageable);

return finalData ;
}
```

Comment: But I did not understand after implementing Specification as well, I need to make sure that my all different specification has to call out only when I get the specific parameters from the client, I feel more over-specification is same with  JPA repository just few sugar coat in the syntex

Comment: Example added @YouAreAwesome

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if you see all the if logic which I wrote in my service to call specific Jpa repo method same is happening at your myEntitySpecification class where I can see.. where you are preparing multiple predicateList and criteriaBuilder the same way I wrote the logic in my service .. so if you see the problem is I wanted to get rid of all these conditions consider in case of 30 attributes the cognitive complicity level would be more then 40 which is not the good practice, let me know you though on this.

Comment: You can always try to have a map of attributes and value, and then iterate over to populate the criteria

Comment: please update the answer.. how this map would help me as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ggr, you can create a method as follows -

```
public Specification<Gateway> getSpecification(Map<String, String> attributeToValueMap) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList();
            attributeToValueMap.forEach((attribute, value) -> {
                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(attribute), value));
                }
            });
            return query.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]))).getRestriction();
        };

    }
```

So basically, instead of taking multiple parameters as separate variables, add them in a Map and pass that map to getSpecification() method.